# Can I still get keys and XP for playing Infinite Warfare zombies solo?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

I play zombies online because it's pretty helpful having three others around, but do I still earn keys and XP if I play solo? If I do, do I earn them faster, since nobody else is in the game to take the zombie kills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do earn keys and XP in solo Zombies.

Keys are based upon the round achieved, so **higher rounds mean more keys**, and that may be easier or harder in solo, depending on your play style.

XP is based upon the player actions you take (opening doors, completing challenges, etc) as well as kills. Playing solo should net you more kills than in multiplayer (assuming you make through as many rounds), and you will be making all the purchases yourself as well, so **in general you should get more XP in a solo game compared to an equal round multiplayer game**.

Comment: My source here is personal experience, if anyone finds anything authoritative I will gladly edit.